# Quadratic modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

What is a fast way of finding a solution M to a quadratic modulus of the form

```
a == M (M + b)  mod n
```

where a and n are very large, and b << a

n is the product of two large primes (RSA modulus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can complete the square so that this is simply asking for a quadratic residue. Now knowing how to find a quadratic residue gives an efficient (and currently unknown) way to factor $n$. Thus, assuming RSA-type numbers where no factorization is known, it can't be done.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_power_modulus) for an algorithm assuming the prime factorization is known.

Comment: @robertkin: Your comment suggests that there is some misunderstanding. I stated precisely your comment in my answer, so please tell me if there is some confusion afoot.